# Putty command line argument to change title

Tags: command-line, putty

I need to launch putty through command line argument programmtically. I am doing this using the command as:

```
C:\Programs\putty.exe -ssh -l root -pw password hostname
```

which works fine. 
Now I want to open the session with changed title of my choice. I know this can be done using

> Disable remote-controller window title changing

and setting

> Window title

But is there any way to pass these parameters as command line argument while launching?

Comment: As far I know that is not possible, you can do it in the batch file with the TITLE command

Comment: You _could_ create a temporary Saved Session by manipluating the registry, and then `-load` it... (eww - don't do that). Alternatively, could the remote set the title for you?

Comment: Let the host send a terminal escape string that sets the title?

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille Can you please post an example? All I want is a putty window that has a title of my choice.

Comment: @ Attie Would prefer not to manipulate the registry. Remote setting the title for me: is there any command that I need to execute post login? Can you please provide an example, would like to try it out through my program in Java.

Comment: Need to know which terminal type putty is emulating.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to get the putty SSH terminal session to change its title by following a few steps as I found in the [Set PuTTY's window title to name of loaded session](https://serverfault.com/questions/178469/set-puttys-window-title-to-name-of-loaded-session/745968) post on **Server Fault**.

> ### Change Window Title of Putty Terminal Session
>
> 1. From the PuTTY app go to **Session** and then define the **Host Name**, **Port**, and **SSH** *connection type*.
>
>    [image]
> 2. From **Terminal -> Features**, then *checked* the **Disable remote-controlled window title changing option**.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Go back to **Session** and then in **Saved Sessions** type in the hostname or session name you want that host to be defined as and press
>      **Save**. You should not see that session in the list.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Now you can load the SSH session with PuTTY via the command line from that same PC but append the `-loghost "My Title"` for the title
>      of the terminal window to have that value in it instead.
>
> **Command**
>
> > ```
> > C:\Programs\putty.exe -load "Hostname" -ssh -l root -pw Password Hostname -loghost "My Title"
> > ```
>
> [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Set PuTTY's window title to name of loaded session?](https://serverfault.com/questions/178469/set-puttys-window-title-to-name-of-loaded-session/745968)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried both the ways. Observed that with login successful, the title of the putty window becomes root@hostname:~. I am required to execute this command from a Java program, and I tried running from both program and a batch file, resulted the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: "Another example" has an unpair number of double quotes.

Comment: Almost there! As I mentioned in the question, performing the manual step of selecting "Disable remote-controlled window title changing" works, but I am launching Putty through another program and I don't have the option to manually select this checkbox. "-loghost" is changing the title before login, but once login is successful, title becomes "root@hostname:~". Is there any parameter to pass in the command itself to do this job? An equivalent of "Disable remote-controlled window title changing"?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, can be IPv4 or IPv6 or dual

Comment: With the input from @Attie, I modified the registry for Default Settings for key NoRemoteWinTitle, resulting not to have remote title for any putty session. Then executed the command as follows to get the desired result:
<pre> <code>CMD /C "start "HA-Primary" C:\Programs\putty.exe -load "Default Settings" -ssh -l root -pw password hostname -loghost "HA-Primary"</pre>/code>

Appreciate all your help and would welcome any comment for further improvement.

Answer (score 1):

what i do to make my life easier,

1) use mtputty application. 
2) edit mtputty.xml file to create/import sessions
3) Under Tools menu > settings > general > 
check - "show display name", instead of "Replicate Putty window caption"